# How to generate a heat map with 3 dimensional scattered data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with one column as latitude, one as longitude, and the other as mm. How can I plot a heat map using latitude and longitude as the grid, and use the mm for the heat value? the mm is not grided. For example:

```
lat = [1,1,2,2]
lon = [1,2,1,2]
mm = [1,2,3,4]
```

or I guess I want to ask how to turn this three lists into a grid:

```
  1  2
1 1  3
2 2  4
```

Comment: How many points are we talking?  If there aren't too many, you could make a dict mapping (latitude, longitude) tuples to heat values.

Comment: It can be several hundreds of data

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't too many points to worry about (less than ~100,000), it should be enough to just map latitude/longitude tuples to a heat-map value, like so:

```
lat = [1,1,2,2]
lon = [1,2,1,2]
mm = [1,2,3,4]

heat_map = dict()
for latitude, longitude, heat_value in zip(lat, lon, mm):
    heat_map[(latitude, longitude)] = heat_value
print(heat_map)
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/EFOP/0)